# Algebra-step in the methods of characterstics for a first-order PDE.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, partial-differential-equations

In the book *Linear PDEs for Scientists and Engineers, 4th ed*, example 2.5.3:
$$x^2u_x +y^2 u_y =(x+y)u$$
Characteristic equations (system of three equations often written this way in books on PDEs)
$$\frac{dx}{x^2}=\frac{dy}{y^2}=\frac{du}{(x+y)u}$$
Integrating the first two terms may yield
$$\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{y}=C_1 $$
Then, the next step in the book is that from the characteristic equation, you can write
$$\frac{dx-dy}{x^2-y^2}=\frac{du}{(x+y)u}$$
I'm perhaps to stupid to ever do math again, but then again everything is obvious once you've seen it

Comment: General solution: $u\! \left(x,y\right)=F\! \left(-\frac{y-x}{y x}\right) x y$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $$\frac{dx}{x^2} = \frac{dy}{x^2} = k$$
Then $dx = kx^2$ and $dy = ky^2$ so $dx - dy = k(x^2-y^2)$ which means
$$\frac{dx-dy}{x^2-y^2} = k$$